# Can you tell me how the code given reachs to that output?

Tags: c++, function, reference

the output of the code is 30.But I am not sure how it is getting to it.

```
#include <iostream>      
int &fun() 
{ 
    static int x = 10; 
    return x; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    fun() = 30; 
    std::cout << fun(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

I am expecting that the output will be 10 but its showing 30. how?

Comment: Why are you expecting the output to be 10?

Comment: Haven't you noticed the `&` in the return type of `fun()`?

Comment: You return by reference thus you can write to the static variable declared.

Comment: @Bathsheba: the question is a basic one about C++, any book on C++ should explain that. We expect people to read stuff before asking here.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: On those grounds, the overwhelming majority of questions on this site should be closed. Who is going to define the threshold for "basic"? You? Me? Someone else?

Comment: I do agree with you, and I find StackOverflow much less interesting than a few years ago. I did answer and I did downvote that question.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Indeed although occasionally a question worth answering comes up - such as this one.

Answer (score 6):

Your `fun` gives a *location* of an `int` (since it returns a [*reference*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization)). That location is the `static` variable `x` which is initialized (once, conceptually before the program runs) to 10.

Then  `fun() = 30;` is *assigning* that location. So `x` gets assigned to 30.

At last `cout << fun()` displays the content of that location.

If `x` was some [automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) your code would have [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

PS. A crude way of thinking about `&` unary reference like `int &r = x;` is that it sort-of "transforms" your code as: introduce a phantom pointer `int *p = &x;` (where `p` is some fresh variable not appearing elsewhere)  and replace `r` with `*p`, so `&r` with `p`, everywhere in the scope of that `r`.